# Counter variable not working?

Tags: php

I'm writing a function to count syllables of a word as follows:

```
function estimate_syllables($word) {
    $total_count=0; 
    foreach($word as $w) {
        $syllable_count = count_english_vowels($w);
        $total_count += $syllable_count; 
    }
    return $total_count;
}

function count_english_vowels($word) {
    static $english_vowels = array('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'Y');
    $vowel_count = 0;
    $letters = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', "", $word);
    $len = strlen($letters); 
    $letters = str_split(strtoupper($letters)); 
    $currPosition = -2; 
    $prevPosition = -1;
    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        if (in_array($letters[$i], $english_vowels)) {
            if($i != $currPosition + 1) {
                if ($letters[$i] == 'E' && $i != ($len -1))
                    $vowel_count++;

                $prevPosition = $currPosition; 
                $currPosition = $i;
            } 
        }
    }
    return $vowel_count;
}
```

I'm really confused: if you pass count_english_vowels a word like water, it reaches the inner loop to the correct syllable twice, yet the counter only reports a 1? Super confused, can anyone figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: Judging by your indentation around `if ($letters[$i] == 'E' && $i != ($len -1))` you expect the next three lines to be in that if statement. However you are missing the brackets; it will only execute `$vowel_count++;` and execute the other code every iteration.

Comment: Also if you don't want to count y's on the end you need another condition in there. As now you just aren't going to count and vowel on the end of a word.

Comment: Try to change `if ($letters[$i] == 'E' && $i != ($len -1))` to `if (!($letters[$i] == 'E' && $i == ($len -1)))` so it will be matched with 'and not last letter E'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only reporting one because of this:

```
if ($letters[$i] == 'E' && $i != ($len -1))
    $vowel_count++;
    $prevPosition = $currPosition; 
    $currPosition = $i;
```

There is only one `E` in `water`, thus it's only executing `$vowel_count++;` once. Based on your indenting of this code, I'd assume you need `{}` brackets around those lines, as without them PHP will only apply the **first** line after an if without them, so if that code is correct your indentation should look like this:

```
if ($letters[$i] == 'E' && $i != ($len -1))
    $vowel_count++;
$prevPosition = $currPosition; 
$currPosition = $i;
```